# How to create reminders for events in android?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am trying to add reminders for events , Here is my code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    long date=new Date().getTime()+120000;
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,date);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, date+10000);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Jazzercise");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group workout");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,"Asia/Calcutta" );

 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {

                Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

                long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
                ContentResolver cr1 = getContentResolver();
                ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
                values1.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 1);
                values1.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
                values1.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
                Uri urii = cr1.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, values1);
                Toast.makeText(this, ""+eventID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




    }




}
 }
```

Application runs fine, I am getting eventID printed in toast at last, but getting no alert. Please help as I am new to this calendar thing.

Comment: do you want to make a sound at a specific time?

Comment: yes and I also want to know that if  '1' is default calendar id?